# Does an ExecutorService get garbage collected when out of scope?

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection, java-8, executorservice

I'm asking this question because I am creating a lot of executor services and while I may already have a memory leak somewhere that needs to be investigated, I think a recent change to the following code actually worsened it, hence I am trying to confirm what is going on:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface BaseConsumer extends Consumer<Path> {
    @Override
    default void accept(final Path path) {
        String name = path.getFileName().toString();
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(runnable -> {
            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable, "documentId=" + name);
            thread.setDaemon(true);
            return thread;
        });
        Future<?> future = service.submit(() -> {
            baseAccept(path);
            return null;
        });
        try {
            future.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    void baseAccept(final Path path) throws Exception;
}
```

Then this `Consumer<Path>` gets called on another thread pool with (usually) N=2 threads, I am not sure if that is relevant.

The question is: Does the `ExecutorService service` go out of scope *and* get garbage collected once `BaseConsumer#accept` has finished?

Comment: I don't get this. Why is there an executor service when you want to wait on `future.get()` anyway ? The service will be garbage collected when all running threads inside it cease. In your case the execution is in sync always since you `submit()` and wait with `get()`.

Comment: @DeepakBala I want to let the execution take place on a named thread, it has to do with it being easier to log. In either case, this code should work.

Comment: That is not a good reason at all to go through the overhead of creating an executor. I do not contest that your code will work. It will. You're better off just executing this synchronously and tweaking the log to write what you want it to. Yes the service will be garbage collected. In your case there is no doubt about the threads completing before the execution leaves the scope of the method.

Comment: @Sanjeev No, it's completely **on**-topic for this site. It's a question about garbage collection in the context of a code example.

Comment: @Sanjeev This has nothing to do with CR. While this code is indeed working, I am asking a question on how to improve the workings of the code with respect to resources. If my intention was to get a full review of this code, then I would've posted this on CR. Please read the Help Center of CR.

Comment: @Sanjeev The question in it's current form would be off-topic for CR. As mentioned it is not about reviewing the Code, but about the mechanism of Garbage-Collection. Additionally I want to mention that OP is quite active on CR, and for this case obviously knows the scope better than you.

Comment: "Extent", not "scope".  The _scope_ of a variable is the set of all of the places in your code where the variable is _visible_.  The _extent_ of a variable is the interval of time during which it exists.  If your function foo() has a local variable named a, and foo() calls bar(), then a no longer is visible (i.e., it's out-of-scope) even though it still exists (still within its extent).  But the variable ceases to exist when foo() returns (end of it's extent).

Comment: +1 for distinguishing between scope and extent.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Does the ExecutorService service go out of scope and get garbage collected once `BaseConsumer.accept()` has finished?

Yes.

Indeed, the associated thread pool should also be garbage collected ... eventually.

The `ExecutorService` that is created by `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` an instance of `FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService`.  That class has `finalize()` method that calls `shutdown()` on the wrapped `ExecutorService` object.  Provided that all outstanding tasks actually terminate, the service object will shut down its thread pool.

(AFAIK, this is not specified.  But it is what is implemented according to the source code, in Java 6 onwards.)

---

> Does adding a finally { service.shutdown(); } in the try-catch around future.get() help in retrieving resources quicker? (not necessarily garbage collecting the service object).

Yes it does.  Calling `shutdown()` causes the threads to be released as soon as the outstanding tasks complete.  That procedure starts immediately, whereas if you just left it to the garbage collector it wouldn't start until the finalizer was called.

Now if the resources were just "ordinary" Java objects, this wouldn't matter.  But in this case, the resource that you are reclaiming is a Java thread, and that has associate operating system resources (e.g. a native thread), and a non-trivial chunk of out-of-heap memory.  So it is maybe worthwhile to do this.

But if you are looking to optimize this, maybe you should be creating a long-lived `ExecutorService` object, and sharing it across multiple "consumer" instances.

Comment: Does adding a `finally { service.shutdown(); }` in the try-catch around `future.get()` help in retrieving *resources* quicker? (not necessarily garbage collecting the `service` object)

Comment: I believe "the associated thread pool should also be garbage collected ... eventually" is no longer accurate as of <https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8195862>.  Empirically, a loop repeatedly calling `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` and `-Xmx25m` fails with OOM, but it succeeds when calling `.shutdown()`.

Answer (score 7):

> I want to let the execution take place on a named thread, it has to do with it being easier to log. In either case, this code should work.

You can do this much simpler/faster

```
Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
String name = t.getName();
try {
    t.setName("My new thread name for this task");
    // do task
} finally {
    t.setName(name);
}
```

This way you can use a named thread without creating a new one.

Comment: @skiwi It's a bit of a hack, but all you really want is a sane thread name for the logger to print out.  BTW This changes `jstack` output as well.  The nice thing is you see a continuous stack trace rather than part of the stack in one thread and part in another.