# Scope of Executor Service in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

Recently I've been using VM template to write some contents to .vm file and then store the contents of vm file as .txt file in my computer. At first, I've been creating seperate thread for each file creation process which is not good due to large no of thread creations within short amount of time. So I thought to go with Thread Pool

Consider the following method

```
public void runHugeNoOfShortTimeTasks() {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
        service.submit(runnableWriteToVMAndConvertToTXTFile());   // Each process would take around 1-3 seconds
    }
}
```

Now consider it takes 0.5 seconds to complete the for loop. If the loop has finished, the process will exit the `runHugeNoOfShortTimeTasks()` method. But the scope of ExecutorService is within that method, so what will happen to Threads in queue and the ones which are processing? Does the Executor service will be garbage collected once the process exits the `runHugeNoOfShortTimeTasks()` method?

Another thing is that what will happen to that fixed thread pool of 100 once all the threads in queue are completed (if it's not going to be garbage collected). Does it'll be always sit in my memory waiting for threads or will it be destoryed once all threads are completed?

Maybe I'm completely wrong with my way of understanding, clarify me if I'm wrong..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953978/does-an-executorservice-get-garbage-collected-when-out-of-scope

Comment: Just by the way, it's pretty bad to write, `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);`. A better choice would be `Executors.newWorkStealingPool()`, which will only create as many threads as the computer can use at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the ExecutorService will not be garbage collected once the `thread` exits `runHugeNoOfShortTimeTasks()`. This is because the threads that the ExecutorService is using to run the tasks still can "reach" the Object. Once all tasks are finished, the threads will exit out and die, and at that point the ExecutorService will be eligible for garbage collection

Comment: Now I'm confused with completely two different answers..

Comment: @user1354678 Benjy Kessler is talking about what happens when a `Process` ends.  You used the words '... process exits... ' in your original question, so that's what he was responding to. A process is a higher level entity that can contain many threads of execution. Once a process ends (like when you close all browser windows, for instance) all threads in those windows will be shut down and all memory reclaimed

Comment: Thanks.. I've even tested it now with my code. Executor service is still alive and the threads are still running even if it exits that runHugeNoOfTasksMethod();

Comment: This is incorrect. The [documentation for Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-) says that, "The threads in the pool will exist until it is explicitly shutdown." So there will be 100 threads active even after all the tasks in the pool finish.

Answer (score 2):

The `ExecutorService` will be garbage collected, but the underlying `ThreadPoolExecutor` will not be garbage collected until all of the tasks finish. If you'll look at the code of `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`, you'll see that it wraps the task in an instance of nested `Worker` class which, as any nested class instance, has an implicit reference to the `ThreadPoolExecutor` object that created it. This `Worker` class is submitted to the `Thread` object for running, thus until the `Thread` is alive it holds a transitive reference to `ThreadPoolExecutor` and keeps it from garbage collection.